# fit_transform output vs components_ in sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I'm trying to understand the values returned by the fit_transform method and the components_ array in sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.html#) it seems fit_transform returns the sparsely represented input data and components_ contain the atoms.

I ran sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning on the digits data set using this code:

```
sample_data=digits.data[:40,:]    
dl = DictionaryLearning(n_components=36, fit_algorithm='lars', transform_algorithm='lasso_lars')
    X_dict = dl.fit_transform(sample_data)
```

When I plot X_dict returned by fit_transform (which according to the docs is the transformed input data) using this code :

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
for i in range(36):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 6, i + 1, xticks=[], yticks=[])
    ax.imshow(X_dict.reshape(-1, 6, 6)[i], cmap='Greys_r',
              interpolation='nearest')
```

this is what I get:
[image]

When I plot the contents of components_ (which should print the atoms) using this code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(6, 6, figsize=(8, 8))

samples = [dl.components_[x].reshape((8, 8)) for x in range(34)]

for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        ax[i, j].set_axis_off()
        ax[i, j].imshow(samples[(i * 5) + j], cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Now my question is, is this correct? From my understanding of dictionary learning, I feel the first image looks more like the atoms and the latter seems more like the transformed input.

Could somebody please explain the difference between atoms and the transformed data and tell me which of these images is which?